# Text in navbar moves beneath collapsed menu toggle - how can I align this correctly?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

On smaller devices the text ("JH") currently moves underneath the collapsed menu toggle on the left side of the navbar - is there a way to align it so that "JH" is level with the menu toggle but on the right side of the navbar instead? I'm struggling with how to achieve this but I'm sure it's very simple. Many thanks in advance, Jon

My code is as follows:-

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button class="navbar-toggle" data-target=".navbar-collapse"
            data-toggle="collapse" type="button"><span class=
            "icon-bar"></span> <span class="icon-bar"></span> <span class=
            "icon-bar"></span></button>
        </div>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
                <li class="active">
                    <a href="http://www.jonhowlett.uk/home.html" class="navbar-brand">JH</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse" id="navbar">


            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">

                <li>
                    <a href="about.html"><span>About</span></a>
                </li>                       

                <li>
                    <a href="resume.html"><span>Resume</span></a>
                </li>                   

                <li>
                    <a href="portfolio.html"><span>Portfolio</span></a>
                </li>

                 <li>
                    <a href="blog.html"><span>Blog</span></a>
                </li>

                <li>
                    <a href="#"><span>Contact</span></a>
                </li>                   
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

http://www.jonhowlett.uk/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put this

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
    <li class="active">
        <a href="http://www.jonhowlett.uk/home.html" class="navbar-brand">JH</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

inside `<div class="navbar-header">`

```
<div class="navbar-header">
    <button class="navbar-toggle" data-target=".navbar-collapse"
    data-toggle="collapse" type="button"><span class=
    "icon-bar"></span> <span class="icon-bar"></span> <span class=
    "icon-bar"></span></button>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
        <li class="active">
            <a href="http://www.jonhowlett.uk/home.html" class="navbar-brand">JH</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're `navbar` has add HTML that shouldn't be necessary. See [docs](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar).

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
   <li class="active">
     <a href="http://www.jonhowlett.uk/home.html" class="navbar-brand">JH</a>
   </li>
</ul>
```

If you want to add a background color to the brand, just use CSS. See example.

```css
.navbar.navbar-custom .navbar-brand {
  background: #e7e7e7;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-custom">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button class="navbar-toggle" data-target=".navbar-collapse" data-toggle="collapse" type="button"><span class="icon-bar"></span>  <span class="icon-bar"></span>  <span class="icon-bar"></span>

      </button> <a class="navbar-brand" href="http://www.jonhowlett.uk/home.html">JH</a>

    </div>
    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse" id="navbar">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li> <a href="about.html"><span>About</span></a>

        </li>
        <li> <a href="resume.html"><span>Resume</span></a>

        </li>
        <li> <a href="portfolio.html"><span>Portfolio</span></a>

        </li>
        <li> <a href="blog.html"><span>Blog</span></a>

        </li>
        <li> <a href="#"><span>Contact</span></a>

        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```